# Is there any way to recover an old iOS save file?

Tags: ios, final-fantasy-tactics

I played Final Fantasy Tactics on my old iphone and got 20+ hours into it. I then went to android and am now back to iphone (please, let's not start a flame war!) and I was wondering if there is any way to recover my old save files?

Is this stuff stored in iCloud? If so, how can I check to see if my save files are there?